# I'm unable to push my bot's slash commands to an array. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

When I try to push my bot's slash commands to an array which I want to use to register my commands, it doesn't seem to get pushed, as when I `console.log` the array, it returns an empty array. But when I log each command individually, it logs properly. Why?

Here is the code I use to push my bot's commands to the array:

```
const commands = []


fs.readdirSync("./commands").forEach(dir => {
  fs.readdir(`./commands/${dir}`, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const jsFiles = files.filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

    if (jsFiles.length <= 0)
      return console.log("[COMMAND HANDLER] - Cannot find any commands!");

    jsFiles.forEach(file => {
      const command = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
      
      commands.push(command)
      
});
console.log(commands)

module.exports = commands
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
fs.readdirSync("./commands").forEach(dir => {
  fs.readdir(`./commands/${dir}`, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const jsFiles = files.filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

    if (jsFiles.length <= 0)
      return console.log("[COMMAND HANDLER] - Cannot find any commands!");

    jsFiles.forEach(file => {
      const command = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
      
      commands.push(command)
      
});
```

with this:

```
const cmdDirectories = fs.readdirSync(`./commands`)
for (const dir of cmdDirectories) {
  const cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

  if (cmdFiles.length <= 0)
      return console.log("[COMMAND HANDLER] - Cannot find any commands!");

  for (const file of cmdFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
    commands.push(command)
  }
}
```

This solution was found purely by experimentation, I do not know how/why this worked. If someone does know how/why this worked, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `readdir` function is asynchronous. If you want to use this code with minimal changes then replace it with `readdirSync`.

Here is the docs with more info: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options

Comment: Even after using `readddirSync`, still logs an empty array.